# xslt works with xalan cli but not from java code

Tags: java, android, xslt, xhtml

Am trying to use XSLT to scrape html content into xml structure, I tested my xslt against the html using XALAN (CLI) and when I was satisfied with the results, I took the xslt file and used it from the java code using the transformer (javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory), below are the testing values that looks similar to the real code & stylesheets.

my html sample data:

```
<html><body class='home'>
        <div >Welcome !!</div>
    <table border='0'><tr><td colspan='2'>asdas</td></tr>
        <tr><td class='footer' colspan='2' align='center'>Disclaimer: The information provided below is for informative purpose only and it is not a legal document.</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan='2'>test;</td></tr>
    <tr><td class='Home' width='50%' aligh='center'> number:</td><td class='Home' width='50%' aligh='center'>515120</td></tr><tr><td class='Home' width='50%' aligh='center'>Connection :</td><td class='Home' width='50%' aligh='center'>123.23</td></tr><tr><td class='Home'>period (month / year):</td><td class='Home'>04/2012</td></tr><tr><td class='Home'>Date:</td><td class='Home'>APRIL     08,2012, 21:35</td></tr>  </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

my xsl only template is:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
<usage_channel>
<head><xsl:value-of select="//div/text()" /></head>
<body><xsl:value-of select="//td/font/text()" /></body>
<footer><xsl:value-of select="body/table/tr[contains(td,'number')]/td[1]/text()" /></footer>
</usage_channel>
</xsl:template>
```

results using XALAN (cli):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><usage_channel><head>Welcome !!</head><body/><footer> number:</footer></usage_channel>
```

results using Java transofmer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<usage_channel>
   <head>Welcome !!</head>
   <body/>
   <footer/>
</usage_channel>
```

I tried all the combinations hoping to catch the values in the td but I failed, what am missing here?

Comment: 1. What you have provided as code isn't a "stylesheet" -- it is just one template.; 2. There is no `usage_channel` present either in the code or in the XML document -- this means that the statement that you got the result performing the transformatin -- is not true! Please, edit the question and make it meaningful and non-contradictory. My guess is that you used different combinations of (XML-document, XSLT-code) in the two cases and this explains why you got two different results.

Comment: Thanks for the comment (I edited the values), Actually the above values are just dummy values that mimics my real case.

Comment: If these are "dummy values" does this mean that you never performed the provided transformation on the provided XML document in both described cases? If so, how could you state what the actual result in each case is?

Comment: the above values are tested and the above results are generated by the Xalan and by the java code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the HMTL data used by the transformer is slightly different from the raw one, due to the usage of HTMLCleaner, so based on that issue most of my XSLT select queries were not valid any more. I had to print out the HTML and discover the issue:

Modified HTML after it is cleaned by HTMLCleaner:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body class="home">
   <div>Welcome !!
   <center>
   <table border="0">
     <tbody>
       <tr><td colspan="2">asdas</td></tr>
       <tr><td class="footer" colspan="2" align="center">Disclaimer: The information provided below is for informative purpose only and it is not a legal document.</td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2">test;</td></tr>
       <tr><td class="Home" width="50%" aligh="center">number:</td><td class="Home" width="50%" aligh="center">515120</td></tr>
       <tr><td class="Home" width="50%" aligh="center">Connection :</td><td class="Home" width="50%" aligh="center">123.23</td></tr>
       <tr><td class="Home">period (month / year):</td><td class="Home">04/2012</td></tr>
       <tr><td class="Home">Date:</td><td class="Home">APRIL     08,2012, 21:35</td></tr>    
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </center>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the new tag `<center>`, that broke most of my queries that were depending on the path `body/table/tr/td`, changing them to `body/div/center/table/tr/td` resolved the issue. Thanks Dimitre for your comments!